Can't access my settings
Today after booting into my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, I faced options like connecting my online accounts, enabling ubuntu pro,sending system info to Canonical etc. which I have never faced before. After skipping all these setup options I notice that all the settings I made to my system before this have been defaulted to the original default settings(for ex: the background has changed to the original background, dark theme to light theme etc.). Further, I can't seem to change these settings. I go to my settings to enable the dark theme but it doesn't switch nor can I change my background. Even my speakers are not working,it says that there are no speakers detected in my settings, but they do show up in my alsamixer. Can't connect bluetooth devices as well. It's like my settings are defaulted and just stuck on the default.
Please help Video displaying all the problems I just mentioned.

A good example of a corrupted OS. What did you do before this happened? Maybe an improper shutdown? Installed some new software? Please edit the question and add some details.

I actually resolved the error. I had mounted my .config directory to a Fedora container because I had this new nvim plugin I wanted to try in my Fedora container. In the container I manipulated the .config directory without realizing those changes will be mirrored outside the container as well. Brought it back to the way it was and everything went back to normal.
What did you mean by a corrupted OS though?
